# Referring to an instance that refers to an instance

Tags: java, class, hashmap, instance

I am not sure if the title to this question is correct.

I have this school assignment where we have to create two classes.

In one class, we define relationships between people e.g. A knows B, and in the other class we ask questions about that, e.g. does A know B?

The first class below defines relationships and gives methods, the second class inquires about them.

I am sure that my mistake lies somewhere in the public boolean 'knowsWithDegree'. Are you able to help?

```
public class SocialGraph {

    private HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    
    public SocialGraph() {   // empty constructor
        map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    }
    
    public void addIndividual(String a) {
        if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
            map.put(a, new ArrayList<String>());
        } else {
    
        }
    }
    
    public boolean hasKnowsArrow(String a, String b) {
        if (map.containsKey(a)) {
            return map.get(a).contains(b);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public void addKnowsArrow(String a, String b) {
    
        if ((!map.containsKey(a) || !map.containsKey(b)) || (hasKnowsArrow(a, b))) {
        } else {
            map.get(a).add(b);
        }
    }
    
    public void removeKnowsArrow(String a, String b) {
    
        if ((!map.containsKey(a) || !map.containsKey(b)) || (!hasKnowsArrow(a, b))) {
        } else {
            map.get(a).remove(b);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean knowsWithDegree(String a, String b, int x) {
        Object[] keys = map.keySet().toArray();
    
        int y;
        y = 0;
    
        if (map.get(a).contains(b)) {
            y = 1;
        } else {
    
            if ((map.get(a).contains(map.get(keys[0]).contains(b))) || (map.get(a).contains(map.get(keys[1]).contains(b))) ||
                    (map.get(a).contains(map.get(keys[2]).contains(b))) || (map.get(a).contains(map.get(keys[3]).contains(b)))) {
                y = 2;
            }
        }
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    
    public class SocialGraphTest {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SocialGraph socialGraph = new SocialGraph();
            socialGraph.addIndividual("Anne");
            socialGraph.addIndividual("Daisy");
            socialGraph.addIndividual("Bob");
            socialGraph.addIndividual("Charlie");
        
        
            socialGraph.addKnowsArrow("Anne", "Bob");
            socialGraph.addKnowsArrow("Anne", "Daisy");
            socialGraph.addKnowsArrow("Bob", "Daisy");
            socialGraph.addKnowsArrow("Bob", "Charlie");
        
            System.out.println(socialGraph.hasKnowsArrow("Anne", "Bob")); //should be true
            System.out.println(socialGraph.hasKnowsArrow("Anne", "Daisy"));//should be true
            System.out.println(socialGraph.hasKnowsArrow("Bob", "Daisy"));//should be true
            System.out.println(socialGraph.hasKnowsArrow("Bob", "Charlie"));//should be true
            System.out.println(socialGraph.hasKnowsArrow("Anne", "Charlie")); //should be false
        
            System.out.println ();
        
            System.out.println (socialGraph.knowsWithDegree ("Anne", "Daisy", 1));
            System.out.println (socialGraph.knowsWithDegree ("Anne", "Charlie", 2));
            System.out.println (socialGraph.knowsWithDegree ("Anne", "Daisy", 3));
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to follow your code with all those `map.get(a)` calls etc. Advice for better readability: if they return the same thing, call it once and assing the return value to a variable with a proper name. Also improve names of your parameters, i.e. `a` and `b` are hard to follow - maybe better use `sourcePerson` and `targetPerson` (source is where the graph traversal starts, target is where it should end).

Comment: As for the logic of your class: try to take one "hop" at a time, i.e. follow the arrows unti you're out of options, reach a cycle (keep a set of people you already checked) or found the target person. Then count how many hops you needed (you might have to carry the value around for certain "routes" if there are more than one way, i.e. Anne knows Daisy directly (1 hop) or via Bob (2 hops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using recursion:

```
        public boolean knowsWithDegree(String a, String b, int x) {
            return knowsWithDegreeRecursive(a, b, x, new HashSet<>());
        }
        
        private boolean knowsWithDegreeRecursive(String a, String b, int x, Set<String> visited) {
            if (x < 1) {
                // x must be at least 1
                return false;
            }
            

            if (map.get(a).contains(b)) {
                // If a knows b, then the number of degrees should be 1
                return x == 1;
            }
            
            if (x == 1) {
                // Since the degree is 1 and a does not know b, then a does not know b to the specified degree
                return false;
            }
            
            // Go through each person that a knows
            for (String c : map.get(a)) {
                
                if (visited.contains(c)) {
                    // We've already checked this person
                    continue;
                }
                
                // Mark c as visited so we don't check them again
                visited.add(c);
                
                // See if this person knows b, with one fewer degree
                // e.g. if we're seeing if a knows b with a degree of 2, then c should know b with a degree of 1
                boolean knowsWithDegree = knowsWithDegreeRecursive(c, b, x - 1, visited);
                
                // If c knows b with the degree minus 1, then a knows b with the specified degree
                if (knowsWithDegree) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
            // a does not know b to the specified degree
            return false;
        }
```

If the order of the `knowsArrows` doesn't matter, I would recommend using `HashSet` in your `map` over `ArrayList`.

Comment: Incredible, thank you! The only issue is that a person can know another person by both 1st as well as 2nd degree, yet this code will skip any further inquiry about that, so if person A knows person B, it will still give false to the question whether A knows B via C, which should be true. But thank you very much, I will try and fiddle with it a little bit tonight, it was very helpful!